# Flask-Login issues - authentication doesn't persist for more than 10 seconds

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have an issue where my authentication doesn't persist but for a few seconds. I make the login_user call on my User object, but after a few seconds, any successive route that is guarded by the @login_required decorator, no longer works... :( I have used this library before and have not encountered this. Any ideas as to how to diagnose?

Answer (score -1):

You do have some options in login_user():

```
from datetime import timedelta
from flask import session

session.permanent = True
login_user(your_user_object, remember=True, duration=timedelta(days=365), force=True)
```

More at: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.login_user

Comment: That's a remember_me cookie, I am curious as to why my session cookie expires so quickly. I can't tell but it's not clear which cooke the flask-login uses for the login_requred decorator. I looked at the Decorator Code and it only checks to see if the current_user is authenticated.